# How to show a featured image inside a post in only 1 single category

Tags: posts, categories, images

Been walking around with my problem now for days and i decided to just go ahead and ask it.

My theme is set that a featured image is not shown in a post, which is what i want.
The problem is, in 1 category, i don't want this.

So, what do i have to do so that if i set a featured image, it shows in the post.
But ONLY for 1 specific category?

Regards

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [in_cateogry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) function to check if the current post is in your special category. And if it is, you can then display the featured image. Something like:

```
if( in_category( 'YOUR CATEGORY ID OR SLUG', get_the_ID() ) ){
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

Obviously replace 'YOUR CATEGORY ID OR SLUG' with proper value.